# Inserting data entry mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, insert

I keep getting this error:
POST http://page/insert.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my JAVASCRIPT

```
function call(){
         // syntax: $.post(URL,data,callback);
           $.post("insertDb.php",
                {
                    address: $("#address").val(),
                    bedroom: $("#postbedroom").val(),
                    bathroom: $("#postbathroom").val(),
                    type: $("#posttype").val(),
                    pet: $("#postpet").val(),
                    price: $("#postprice").val(),
                    img: $("#postimg").val()

                }
                , display
            );
        }
```

Here is my PHP

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect('###', '###', '###', '###');
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `property` (address, bedroom, bathroom, type, pet_friendly, price, img_path) 
VALUES 
 ('".$_POST['address']."', '".$_POST['bedroom']."', '".$_POST['bathroom']."', '".$_POST['type']."', '".$_POST['pet']."', '".$_POST['price']."','".$_POST['img']."' )";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

I just omitted the connection for security reasons.

Can someone please help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Btw, you should use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating the SQL-string. Right now, you are wide open to SQL-injections.

Comment: Have you used .htaccess file ?

Comment: Error log does not show anything.

Comment: Magnus, can you explain a little better ? Thanks !